# WCSession activate session not calling delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, watchkit, wcsession

I have this code written in my Manager class init method.

```
if([WCSession isSupported]) {
   WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
   session.delegate = self;
   [session activateSession];
}
```

Also, implemented these delegate methods in manager class.

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session activationDidCompleteWithState:(WCSessionActivationState)activationState error:(NSError *)error {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }

    NSLog(@"iOS App Session activated.");
}

- (void)sessionDidBecomeInactive:(nonnull WCSession *)session {
    //
}


- (void)sessionDidDeactivate:(nonnull WCSession *)session {
    //
}

- (void)sessionReachabilityDidChange:(WCSession *)session {
    //
}
```

Watch app InterfaceController delegate method:

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext {
    //
}
```

My problems are:

1. **activationDidCompleteWithState** is never being called.
2. I am calling updateContext method to send data to watch app but **didReceiveApplicationContext** method never being called in InterfaceController.

Answer (score 0):

You have to retain the WCSession object in a member variable.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) WCSession* wcSession;
...

if ([WCSession isSupported])
{
    self.wcSession = [WCSession defaultSession];
    self.wcSession.delegate = self;
    [self.wcSession activateSession];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for above issue. It is the problem with simulators. So I would prefer to test Watch app with real device. My same code is working fine when tested with real device.

Comment: **As a note here**: It works w/ simulators as well. My envirn: Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500).